# Jquery: remove last 4 "li" from ul

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to shorten an unordered list?

```
<ul class="aside-list">
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
  <li class="bordered-item">One</li>
</ul>
```

And I'm trying to find a way to remove "x" nodes from UL.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `slice()` function,

```
$('ul > li').slice(-4).remove()
```

You can specify x in the slice function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bordered-item').slice(-4).remove(); //removes last four
$('ul > li:contains("x")').remove();    //removes <li>s containing "x"
```